# Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to call some javascript functions sitting in an html page running inside an android webview.  Pretty simple what the code tries to do below - from the android app, call a javascript function with a test message, which inturn calls a java function back in the android app that displays test message via toast.

The javascript function looks like:

```
function testEcho(message){
     window.JSInterface.doEchoTest(message);
}
```

From the WebView, I have tried calling the javascript the following ways with no luck:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho(Hello World!)");
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function () { " + "testEcho(Hello World!);" + "})()");
```

I did enable javascript on the WebView

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
// register class containing methods to be exposed to JavaScript
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(myJSInterface, "JSInterface");
```

And heres the Java Class

```
public class JSInterface{

private WebView mAppView;
public JSInterface  (WebView appView) {
        this.mAppView = appView;
    }

    public void doEchoTest(String echo){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mAppView.getContext(), echo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

I've spent a lot of time googling around to see what I may be doing wrong.  All examples I have found use this approach.  Does anyone see something wrong here?

**Edit:**  There are several other external javascript files being referenced & used in the html, could they be the issue?

Comment: The code you try to use misses quotes on the javascript side.

Comment: Please note that since Android 4.2 you're required to use the `@JavascriptInterface` decorator on the Java methods that you want to make available to the WebView through the JavaScript Interface.

Comment: From the code `myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho('Hello World!')");` I understand that you have already attached the html file to that webview. Could you tell me how did you do that?

Answer (score 216):

I figured out what the issue was : missing quotes in the testEcho() parameter.  This is how I got the call to work:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho('Hello World!')");
```

Comment: please have a look in these link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079374/webview-to-load-the-local-html-file-which-contains-js-as-script-src

Comment: It's nice, but how do you pass on a Java object to a JavaScript function as argument?

Comment: @KovácsImre String.Format("javascript: testEcho('%d', '%d', '%d')", 1, 2, 3); I guess

Comment: Starting with KitKat there is the evaluateJavascript method, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/32163655/3063226

Comment: @user457015 hi, can you please help me at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63498385/how-to-pass-parameters-in-webview?

Answer (score 139):

From kitkat onwards use evaluateJavascript method instead loadUrl to call the javascript functions like below

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        webView.evaluateJavascript("enable();", null);
    } else {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:enable();");
    }
```

Comment: why to use evaluateJavascript() instead of loadUrl()?

Comment: @kami loadUrl() will reload the page and call onPageFinished() again

Comment: @Zach It is still an issue on pre-KitKat then, isn't it?

Comment: @kami Adding to Zach answer, evaluateJavascript(), will run JavaScript asynchronously. So we can avoid blocking UI thread using evaluateJavascript().

Comment: `loadUrl` also caused the software keyboard show up when I try to fill in the value  in an input field.

Answer (score 37):

```
public void run(final String scriptSrc) { 
        webView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + scriptSrc); 
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: and if this doesn't work, do new Thread(new Runnaable(){..<like above>..}).start()

Answer (score 31):

I created a nice wrapper to call JavaScript methods; it also shows JavaScript errors in log:

```
private void callJavaScript(String methodName, Object...params){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("javascript:try{");
    stringBuilder.append(methodName);
    stringBuilder.append("(");
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        Object param = params[i];
        if(param instanceof String){
            stringBuilder.append("'");
            stringBuilder.append(param.toString().replace("'", "\\'"));
            stringBuilder.append("'");
        }
        if(i < params.length - 1){
            stringBuilder.append(",");
        }
    }
    stringBuilder.append(")}catch(error){Android.onError(error.message);}");
    webView.loadUrl(stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

You need to add this too:

```
private class WebViewInterface{

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onError(String error){
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}
```

And add this interface to your webview:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewInterface(), "AndroidErrorReporter");
```

Comment: This function, however good as an idea, has wrong implementantion. This call: `final Object a = new Object(); callJavaScript(mBrowser, "alert", 1, true, "abc", a);` will yield to `SyntaxError` with `Unexpected token` which is not surprising when you will look at the generated js call: `javascript:try{alert(,,'abc',,)}catch(error){console.error(error.message);}`

Comment: Even simple call `callJavaScript(mBrowser, "alert", "abc", "def");` generates error as there is always rogue comma at the end. -1 from me.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela tnx, I fixed that. P.S Next time don't be lazy you could fix it yourself... ;)

Comment: For future reference: Let's stay positive.  Pointing out an error in the code is not lazy.  It's still helpful feedback.

Comment: I guess this will not work if any of the parameter has ' character in it?
Example: `callJavascript(mBrowser, "can't do it");`

Comment: I just edited the answer and added the escape to (') character.

Answer (score 18):

Yes you have the syntax error. If you want to get your Javascript errors and printing statements in your logcat you must implement the `onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm)` method in your WebChromeClient. It gives the complete stack traces like Web console(Inspect element). Here is the method.

```
public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) 
    {
        Log.d("Message", cm.message() + " -- From line "
                             + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                             + cm.sourceId() );
        return true;
    }
```

After implementation you will get your Javascript errors and print statements (`console.log`) on your logcat.

Comment: I believe the is on the WebChromeClient and not the WebViewClient.

Comment: Yes you are correct @MichaelLevy. Thanks for pointing me for that mistake. Now I have edited  my answer.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was a just what I needed. I'd also suggest people override onJsAlert() in the WebChromeClient. The combination of javascript logging and alerts can be really helpful when debugging Javascript hosted in the webview.

Answer (score 17):

Modification of @Ilya_Gazman answer

```
    private void callJavaScript(WebView view, String methodName, Object...params){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("javascript:try{");
        stringBuilder.append(methodName);
        stringBuilder.append("(");
        String separator = "";
        for (Object param : params) {               
            stringBuilder.append(separator);
            separator = ",";
            if(param instanceof String){
                stringBuilder.append("'");
            }
                stringBuilder.append(param.toString().replace("'", "\\'"));
            if(param instanceof String){
                stringBuilder.append("'");
            }

        }
        stringBuilder.append(")}catch(error){console.error(error.message);}");
        final String call = stringBuilder.toString();
        Log.i(TAG, "callJavaScript: call="+call);


        view.loadUrl(call);
    }
```

will correctly create JS calls e.g.

```
callJavaScript(mBrowser, "alert", "abc", "def");
//javascript:try{alert('abc','def')}catch(error){console.error(error.message);}
callJavaScript(mBrowser, "alert", 1, true, "abc");
//javascript:try{alert(1,true,'abc')}catch(error){console.error(error.message);}
```

Note that objects will not be passed correctly - but you can serialize them before passing as an argument.

Also I've changed where the error goes, I've diverted it to the console log which can be listened by:

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient());
```

and client

```
class CustomWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    private static final String TAG = "CustomWebChromeClient";

    @Override
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s @ %d: %s", cm.message(),
                cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId()));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this method escape ' character inside of any variable?
In other words, will it work with: `callJavascript(mBrowser, "can't do it");` ?

Comment: Just edited the answer and added the escape to ' character

Answer (score 7):

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.bluapp.androidview.R;

public class WebViewActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view3);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webview1.html");


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String weburl){
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho('Javascript function in webview')");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

assets file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>WebView1</title>
<meta forua="true" http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=0"/>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#212121">
<script type="text/javascript">
function testEcho(p1){
document.write(p1);
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to load js script from the asset on `WebView`.
Put script to a file will help reading easier
I load the script in `onPageFinished` because I need to access some DOM element inside the script (to able to access it should be loaded or it will be null). Depend on the purpose of the script, we may load it earlier

**assets/myjsfile.js**

```
document.getElementById("abc").innerText = "def"
document.getElementById("abc").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("abc").innerText = "abc"
}
```

**WebViewActivity**

```
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
   
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)

        val script = readTextFromAsset("myjsfile.js")
        view.loadUrl("javascript: $script")
    }
}

fun readTextFromAsset(context: Context, fileName: String): String {
    return context.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() 
}
```