# Execute Javascript in HTML file from within Android

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am using Android and I have an HTML file which contains some Javascript. However, I am not able to get the Javascript code to execute. What do I need to do in order to run this code? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Call `getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` on your `WebView`, as JavaScript is disabled by default.

Answer (score 6):

*@raj asked for credible and/or official sources*

@CommonsWare answered:

> Call `getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` on your `WebView`

A simple search for the Android documentation provides the following official sources:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29

Answer (score 0):

Here are few sources that will be surly helpful to you.

1. [Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)
2. [call javascript inside webview](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html).
3. [calling javascript function](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in/2011/10/calling-javascript-function-from.html).

Hope this links will be helpful to you.