# Android: How to save html file with user filled out form

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I was able to download this form to my sdcard (from a given URL):
[image]

My app can access this form via the android web view. My question is, how to save it to a text file after a user filled data to the form? I want to save in the text file the data inputted by the user, for instance:

```
Address: User address here
City: User City
Province: User Province here
Zip: 4342343
Phone: 4534534534
What is your biggest regret in your life? None.
```

will be saved to the text file... 
I'm kinda new to java and android dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the data locally, you should implement this form as a widget-based `Activity` rather than using a `WebView`.

If these values should be processed by a server, submit it like any other HTML form and let the server pick the values from the HTTP POST request.

**EDIT**

It is possible to attach a `WebViewClient` to the `WebView`, to allow methods in the `WebView`'s `Activity` to be called from JavaScript. See [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/src/com/google/android/webviewdemo/WebViewDemo.java#).

Your HTML file would need to contain JavaScript that runs when the "Submit" button is clicked,  collects the contents of the form and then passes it to the `WebViewClient`.

(There might be an even easier way, see: [Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview))

Comment: Thank you for your response Jen, yes I want to store it locally, hmm what do you mean by widget-based activity?

Comment: Instead of using HTML-based text fields, use a `TextView` for each field. Her's a tutorial: http://coenraets.org/blog/android-samples/androidtutorial/. Have a look at Step 5, which shows how to create the `Activity`: http://code.google.com/p/androidtutorial/source/browse/trunk/%20androidtutorial/EmployeeDirectory5/src/samples/employeedirectory/EmployeeDetails.java

Comment: But the text fields here is dynamic. They are downloaded from a URL (given by XML). Is there a way to convert those fields to android text views dynamically?

Comment: 1. How often do the questions change? 2. If a server generates the questions, wouldn't it make more sense for the server to process the responses?

Comment: I've just posted this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056860/android-how-to-interact-with-the-content-in-a-webview

Comment: 1. The questions change frequently. 2. the devices will be offline once the questions were downloaded.. we want the app to be responsive coz if our server processes it, it is very slow...

Comment: Wow thanks for posting related question, you're so generous :)

Comment: It's an interesting topic, and it does look like a very good reason to use `WebView`