# Android: How to interact with the contents of a WebView?

Tags: android, webview

Is there a way to programmatically interact with the contents of a `WebView`?

For example, how could my app:

1. respond to an event (such as button clicked on a web page)
2. iterate through all the `INPUT` elements in a page and retrieve their contents?
3. Find all `DIV` elements with the class `status` and change their content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Javascript to make a callback to Java for anything that Javascript can detect.

You can see a demo call JS to Java here: [Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)

Comment: Thanks! How do I set up such a callback?

Comment: Got it -- I can use a `WebChromeClient` as demonstrated here: http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/src/com/google/android/webviewdemo/WebViewDemo.java#

Comment: @TonythePony I think [this is the correct URL](https://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/Samples/WebViewDemo/src/com/google/android/webviewdemo/WebViewDemo.java)