# How to write data from local javascript/html to local file on android

Tags: android

following problem, an android tablet without any internet connection has to run a small html form and store the filled out form on the device. I've played around with http://phpforandroid.net but don't get the connection between html form called in browser to the php processing part which would be the easiest way I guess. Simply pass on the data from the formular to the php processor and write it into a csv. I also tried out http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html this JQuery extension which is working fine in firefox but it's not working on the mobile device.

Any ideas appreciated... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call methods in your app from JavaScript if the HTML page is displayed in a `WebView`.

See this question: [Android: How to save html file with user filled out form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056471/android-how-to-save-html-file-with-user-filled-out-form/6056609#6056609)