# Android: share java data with javascript?

Tags: android

I hava a programme contains java and javascript(webview).
Now, in java

```
String vi = "I am a student";
```

In javascript

```
var fromvi;
```

How can I get the value in java String "vi" and set this value into javascript var "fromvi"?
Thanks!

Comment: Need some more context. Where does the Javascript live? This is tagged Android. So is this a WebView embedded in your activity?

Comment: I believe you are searching for something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AddJavascriptInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) will allow you to bind a Java object to a WebView and control it with Javascript.