# Send a value from Javascript to Android

Tags: php, javascript, android, android-webview

I am making an app that conects to a server from where it needs to get a path wich will use after for upload files to that server.

In the app, there is a webview that display webpage with the options. When you touch/click in one button... lets say, "get url" it is suposed to send the url(a simple string value) from the server to the app.

In the app I was thinking that it could be something like this.

```
class JSInterface {

public void getUrl(String URL) {
MainActivity.doSomethingWithUrl(URL);
}
}
```

In the server side:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
   function sendUrl() {
      Android.getUrl() 
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="sendUrl" onClick="sendUrl()" />
</body>
</html>
```

In the js sendURL function is where I dont know what to do.
PD: The server backend is php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000717/passing-and-returning-value-from-javascript-to-android

Comment: And, linked to in that other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982570/pass-and-return-the-values-from-javascript-and-android-and-use-as-a-phone-gap-pl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about the addJavaScriptInterface method of the webView:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29

Some more reading here: [Understanding Android's webview addjavascriptinterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962150/understanding-androids-webview-addjavascriptinterface)

It shouldn't be hard to find more information if you need it.