# Native code calling JS in Android webapps

Tags: android, html, native

I am writing an Android "web" app (I will not upload the APP to the web, but set the HTML+JS inside the application resources). That means, the GUI will be HTML5, and I will use another "native" thread to read from the microphone and hopefully send the "parsed text" to the HTML5/JS code.

Is this possible? In the Android code, I see how can I call native code from JS (and I want the opposite).

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: OMG, I am calling Java native... what happened to the world....

Comment: DUP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Android rocks at this actually.

I'm posting example code from a random example app that I made but this should get you going.

Lets start by supposing you have to global variable to your webview controlling class:

```
String name = "John";
String lastName = "Doe";
```

In the Android class controlling the webview (during `onCreate()` or when you setup your webview):

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "android")
```

Inner class to your webview controlling class:

```
/**
* Sets up the interface for getting access to Latitude and Longitude data
* from device
**/
private class JavaScriptInterface {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void onJavascriptButtonPushed(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(WebViewControllingClass.this, "The text of the pressed button is: "+text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Thats it for the Android side, now to use it through Javascript:

To get the name and lastname through JavaScript:

```
if (window.android){
    name = window.android.getName();
    lastName = window.android.getLastName();
}
```

If you want to raise the toast, set a javascript whose function would be:

```
if (window.android){
    window.android.onJavascriptButtonPushed("Hello");
}
```

**Edit:**

I havent tried this, but a [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview) yielded this, try it out, it should work.

**If you want to use it in the other direction:**

JS:

```
function testEcho(message){
     window.JSInterface.doEchoTest(message);
}
```

Android:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho('Hello World!')");
```

Comment: No, I want the other way. I want to push events from Java to Javascript.

Comment: Oh, sorry, one second. I missunderstood.

Comment: You can push events from Java to JS using the same JS bridge, however you must write your JS functions to receive this (or JS vars), than via webView.loadUtl("<load your JS code>"); ,actually you can do this on both ways, setting and getting values from the HTML5 page, since the page is running inside the Webview component.