# An alternative to URL schemes on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, url-scheme

I need to support the launching of native apps from a web application. Considering that not all the apps support URL schemes, is there an alternative to launch native apps from Web without URL scheme on Android?

I'm looking for JavaScript solutions that will work on Android 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at this-https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents..I think native apps and chrome webview on phone must be supporting this.

If your app is a hybrid one-you can try this:

You can have a method called launchNative(appName) in your native code and call it from javascript.refer-[Native code calling JS in Android webapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218093/native-code-calling-js-in-android-webapps)

Comment: Hello @rupesh, in the first link  it said:
_To launch the Zxing barcode scanner app, you encode your href on the anchor as follows:_
  <a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>`

Comment: How do I know what to write in here (I mean in the intent or the href) if I don't have access to the manifiest?

Comment: The app which you are trying to launch must be listening for some action..For eg..if you want to launch gallery you specify ACTION_PICK and data as images..