# how to click button at website in android

Tags: android, web, hyperlink, click

I am parsing the site using Jsoup. everything is ok, but there are 2 links on the site (such as "+" and "-" to rate the story)

for example, link for "+":

`<a class="votelink" href="/vote/yes/985dbab6-9bfb-11e1-99eb-f23c91df8b43">bla bla bla</a>`

js function located at website for this link is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".votelink").click(function(e)
    {
        $.get(this);
        this.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = 'bla bla bla'
        e.preventDefault();
     })
});
```

so my question is: how can I add actions on my Buttons and using this actions perform a click on the link at website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your buttons link to urls you can know, just call them.

Otherwise, use a webview, load the page and call some javascript function to click on the buttons :

[Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)