# calling web service using html in android

Tags: android, web-services

I designed the android UI using HTML.Now I want to call web service in that html page. 
I tried a code for calling webservice using javascript in html. But it didn't work for me. I think it is because of the browser used in android emulator.

Please give me  code to call webservice using HTML.

Thanx......

Answer (score 0):

Similar question found here

[Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)

you need to call java method, and inside java method you can call webservice.