# Error changing element height in webview using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to change height of a field in webView(Android). I tried doing it using a javascript but it doesn't work.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(var field = document.getElementById("targetdiv");field.style.height='50px;);");
```

I've also enabled javascript:

```
WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Still it doesn't work. Please help me out !

Answer (score 1):

This works along like this

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:showString('Hello World!')");
```

where showStringis a function that outputs the given string (not shwon here).

Comment: I'm new to javascript. I've written one: webView.loadUrl("javascript:(var field = document.getElementById ("targetdiv");field.style.height='50px;);");

Can u help me in correcting it. Thanks !

Comment: this will set the variable, but there will be no output - but you have (probalby) executed javascript in webView

Comment: for a hello World programm see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview

Comment: you will need to define a function: function switchValues(){"...your code here..."}; and execute this function using mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:switchValues");

Comment: You mean I need to define function in HTML. But I'm getting HTML from server and its not defined locally.

Comment: Its not possible at my end. Is there any other way I could achieve this. Thanks !

Comment: there might be, but there is none i know of - sry