# Access SQLite database from inside an Android asset file

Tags: android, sqlite, openlayers, android-sqlite, openstreetmap

OK, here's the situation:

I am making an app that contains a webView, in which I am displaying an OpenStreetMap using [OpenLayers](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/introduction.html). I have stored the html for this as an asset file and point to that for my webView.loadUrl(asset_file_path) so it displays in the webView. The app also has database, which has a bunch of location point data (different kinds of volcanoes!) that I would like to dynamically display on the map, based on user input.

In order to display the location data from the database, this needs to be placed in the html asset file so that OpenLayers can work its magic and put the points on the map. (please correct me if I am wrong and there is a better way to do this?)

So, here's my question. Assuming that the location data from my database does somehow need to get into my html, how do I access the app SQLite database from the asset file and put it in there? I *really* don't want to dynamically generate the html asset file, but I can't think of any other way to do this. Is there a way to hook on to the SQLite database from an asset file somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly access the database from the HTML/JavaScript. What you can do however, is to inject it from the outside. You can call a Javascript method from the android code and pass the values as parameter. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview) for an example. Vise versa, you can also call a method in the Android code from the Javascript. An example can be found in the Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript).