# Create android application just register screen, after that only webview

Tags: android, authentication, webview

is that possible make application android apk, 
when opening the app, is display form register screen.
When success register is saved on database online and waiting confirmation from administrator.
when account is active, close the app and open app again.
and display a webview.

How to check the mobile is success active register permanently on internal storaga then send to server for check.? is that possible?
Use native and webview for success register. how the concept for that. ?
Thanks hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily implement all your desired features by writing Android part in Java, JavaScript part for WebView and then calling WebView JavaScript from Android code and Android code from JavaScript. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview) on how to do this.

Comment: nice opinion sir ! Thank you so much