# Programmatically perform action on button of a web page

Tags: javascript, android, selenium, jsoup, htmlunit

I am building an android application to access a website using web scraping. I want to go to a particular web page by clicking button on current web page programmatically. This is the HTML element correspond to the button click.

```
    form method="post" action="http://localhost/example/start.php">
    <div><input type="submit" value="Start" id="someValue1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="value1" /></div></form>
```

When I click on the button popup dialog box appears asking whether I want to go to that page or not.So I have to click on "Yes" or "No" button of popup window too.That popup dialog box appearing is caused by  following code on source of webpage.

```
    Y.on('click', M.util.show_confirm_dialog, "#someValue1", null, 
    {"message":"Are you sure that you want to continue?","continuelabel":"Start
    ","cancellabel":null});
```

I tried to perform action on click button using Jsoup, HtmlUnit, Selenium programmatically. But I couldn't success.Please give me a way to do this.

Comment: Just in case you were not aware, this is a really unreliable thing to be doing, what is the website changes its source, layout, urls, filenames etc?

Comment: @BenjaminPaul The website is a Moodle site. So that's not a case

Answer (score 0):

you can use the url of the webview to call javascript
[Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)
so, just send a command like `javascript:document.getElementById("myId").onclick();`

Comment: I tried your method to log a web site programmatically.But It only fills the textfields from given values, does not perform click on the button.What's the wrong with my code?   webView.loadUrl("javascript:"document.getElementById('username').value = '"+user+"';" +"document.getElementById('password').value = '"+pass+"';"+"document.getElementByName('submit').onclick();""};");