# How to speak to a html loaded in a webview from the activity

Tags: android, jquery, html, webview, slidetoggle

I have a html file in my assets that I load via:

```
webView.loadUrl(""file:///android_asset/subfolder/myhtmldoc.html",");
```

Inside that html file I have a accordion-table.

So when I search via:

```
mwebView.findAllAsync("searchterm");
```

it finds only the words in the open accords....

I want to open all the accords when I search. And optimal would be to close all that does not contain the word but that comes secondary.

Inside the html I have written a jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- erzeugt die akkordeonansicht zum aufklappen -->
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("dt").click(function(){ // trigger 
                $(this).next("dd").slideToggle("fast"); // blendet beim Klick auf "dt" die nächste "dd" ein. 
                $(this).children("a").toggleClass("closed open"); // wechselt beim Klick auf "dt" die Klasse des enthaltenen a-Tags von "closed" zu "open". 
            });
        });
</script>
```

Now how do I tell that html to slide down all the Toggles when I search inside it?

It should look somewhat like this:

```
mwebview.passCommand("$("dt").$(this).next("dd").slideToggle("fast");");
```

Comment: I also found this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview/4330642#4330642): reffering to the topic!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call any js function by using `loadUrl` method of WebView:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction();");
```

In your case:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:$('dt').$(this).next('dd').slideToggle('fast');");
```

Comment: Ahm that doesen't seem to work? :-(     
My Java says it doesen't know '$'

Comment: I forgot to add `javascript:` in the second case. I want to say that you can perform js code by calling `webView.loadUrl("javascript:...");`

Comment: I mean this works:
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:$('dt').next('dd').slideToggle('fast');");
but this doesen't:
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:$("dt").next("dd").slideToggle("fast");");

some kind of obvious

Comment: Yes, another way to do this is escape quotes with backslash:
`webView.loadUrl("javascript:$(\"dt\").next(\"dd\").slideToggle(\"fast\");");`