# WebView controller Android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am working on **WebView**. I don't know whether it's possible or not. I am opening an url inside of this view which is basically a login page. Now want to get the information whether user has successfully logged in or not. If yes then navigate to custom page (*Android native*) else keep on that page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use JS to parse that information and then send it to the native Android side using Java-JS bridge http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

Comment: @user527759 thanks for quick response. but i will come to know whether he has successfully logged in or not. I have no control over webview.

Comment: You can parse HTML DOM or use some Javascript function in your page to provide that information

Comment: @user527759 are you talking about login page to put some javascript function. Then i have no control if you are saying for my code. Where and how you want me put that piece of code.

Comment: You can load any Javascript code to the loaded page using `loadUrl("javascript:<some code>")` call or `evaluateJavascript` call in Kit-Kat and above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve it via using this..

1. Create a function of javascript in the HTML page of Login Success/Failue HtmL page.
2. in this javascript function ,call your native Function by Using addJavascriptInterface:

```java
 package com.example.androidjsdemo;

 import java.io.File;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Here you can Start WhatEver Activty launch///////
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webMy = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webMy);
    webMy.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    WebSettings setting = webMy.getSettings();
    setting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //File file = new File("andoid");
    webMy.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mine.html");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}

 mine.html


<HTML>
<script>
function called()
{
  // alert("hi");
  Android.showToast("Hi Testing");
}
</script>
<Body>
Hi Sumit
<button onclick="called()">click me</button>
</Body>
</HTML>

activity_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"

 tools:context="com.example.androidjsdemo.MainActivity" >

 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webMy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When user complete successful singing he should redirect to other web page with url that indicate the login was successful. it can look something like `http://www.yourwebsite.com/islogin?yes`.
than all you need to do is to check in your app what the login status by verify that the url contain `islogin` and that it set to `yes` and do whatever you want.

here a small sample to help you begin:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(isUserLoggedIn(url)){
                doWork();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For Example below is your login URL which you load in webview for login

```
String loginURL = "http://www.myurl.com/login";
```

Two possibility, when user click on login button

1) Success

> > Navigate to Other page as per web code. So we need to check it and open our native application screen.

2) Fail

> > Same login page but display error message according to user input.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.contains(loginURL)) {
                    // Login Fail
                    return false;
                } else {
                    // Login Success 
                    // Open Android Native screen
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
```