# Xamarin Android two way communication between Javascript and C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing an app using Xamarin Android which has a WebView displaying a web page. I want to implement a two way communication between Javascript from WebView to c#. I could call C# from Javascript using this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/webview/call_csharp_from_javascript/). However i couldn't find a way to send data back from C# to Javascript. 
Is there a way to send data back and forth in this approach. I thought writing a callback in Javascript would work but how to fire it from C# code.

Now, My problem is how to call WebView from a javascript interface class. I have a Javascript interface class as mentioned https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/webview/call_csharp_from_javascript/
     namespace ScannerAndroid
     {
      public class JSInterface: Java.Lang.Object
      {
        Context context;
        WebView webView;

```
    public JSInterface (Context context, WebView webView1)
    {
      this.context = context;
      this.webView = webView1;
    }

    [Export]
    [JavascriptInterface]
    public void ShowToast()
    {
      Toast.MakeText (context, "Hello from C#", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
      this.webView.LoadUrl ("javascript:callback('Hello from Android Native');");

    }   
  }
}
```

The code throws an exception at LoadUrl line. java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'Thread-891'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {42ce58a0} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {42ce58a0})

Now i am struggling how to refer the WebView from this Java script interface class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That is possible. If you are targeting KitKat or higher you can use:

```
webView.EvaluateJavascript("enable();", null);
```

Where in this case `enable();` is a JS function.

If you are targeting lower API levels you can use `LoadUrl();`:

```
webView.LoadUrl("javascript:enable();");
```

**EDIT:**

The error you get where it complains on `LoadUrl` is because it for some reason happens on a non-UI thread.

Since you have already passed on the `Context` into your JavascriptInterface class, then you can simply wrap the contents of `ShowToast` in:

```
context.RunOnUiThread(() => {
   // stuff here
});
```

Just change signature from `Context` to `Activity` and it should help you marshal you back on UI thread.

Comment: My problem is who to call WebView from a javascript interface class. I have a Javascript interface class as mentioned https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/webview/call_csharp_from_javascript/

Comment: I don't understand what "how to call WebView from javascript interface class" is. What do you mean?

Comment: Cheesebaron please see details below.

Comment: Please edit your original question rather than creating an answer.