# Injecting JavaScript into WebView in Android 6

Tags: javascript, android, webview, xamarin, android-6.0-marshmallow

So recently I was trying to build my app for Android 6 by setting the `android:targetSdkVersion="23"` in the manifest file, everything went well but then I noticed the strange behavior of webview.

In my app I first load some content into the webview using the `webview.LoadData (someHtmlContent, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);` then at any point user can change the text size by using some buttons in the menu of the app. These buttons work like this:

`webview.LoadUrl ("javascript:" + "document.getElementsByTagName(\"body\")[0].style.fontSize = \"" + size + "%\";");`

`size` is a string that can be anything from `100%` (Initial size) to `110%`, `120%` and ...

This method effectively injects JavaScript into the already existing content (HTML) and works perfectly on Android 5 and lower but not on Android 6.

In Android 6, when user clicks a button that injects JS, it just **replaces** the content of webview with the `size` variable.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why `LoadUrl` method of `webview` didn't work but I just found out about a new method `EvaluateJavascript` that should be used for Android 4.4 and up. I just tested this with my app (Android 6) and it works fine.

So, the following code should be used instead: (I'm using C#/Xamarin)

```
if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 19)
{
    webview.EvaluateJavascript ("document.getElementsByTagName(\"body\")[0].style.fontSize = \"" + size + "%\";", null);
}
else
{
    webview.LoadUrl ("javascript:" + "document.getElementsByTagName(\"body\")[0].style.fontSize = \"" + size + "%\";");
}
```

[Here there's a Java Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31291128/5173926)