# How can we play Scorm content in mobile devices (iOS & Android)?

Tags: ios, playback, scorm

We need to play scorm files in our application, how can we play the same in both Android and iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to do some research on the webview in android and iOS.  SCO's (Shareable Content Objects) are commonly portable websites.  Please understand content in HTML will be fine, but some can use other plugins which may make this more challenging (like flash).

You would either need to established your mobile app like a LMS exposing the SCORM runtime to bridge the JavaScript between your webview and SCO for SCORM communication.

Possibly more info here [Using Javascript bridge in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657311/using-javascript-bridge-in-android)

I've assisted other customers implementing this so I know it's possible.