# Modify HTML file of android assets

Tags: java, android, webview, assets

In android, I have loaded **Webview** with assets directory html files and I want to modfiy these html file from java code. Any code to modify it?
I am novice to WebView. **Thanks in advance!**

**Updated**

According to the following answers, we can't modify or update the files of assets folder.So, any other ways possible without using Internal or External Storage?

Comment: what do you mean by want to change html file?
is it mean change some value on html page or something else ?
if this is the case call the java script method from your java and through JavaScript change the the intended value

Comment: you can call java script method as mention in link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview

Comment: I mean is that I want to modify html file from asset directory and re-save it in that asset folder. Can it be? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot write to assets file, alternate you can store the file to the internal store after modifying and read from that place.