# Filling Forms Automatically With Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, forms, webview, autofill

I'm new to Android development and I am trying to make an app that will open a website and automatically set the username and password in the login form that appears.

Here is the code that I written to do this:

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.bhos.edu.az/az/login?r=http://www.bhos.edu.az/az/page/67-imtahan-naticalari");
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        String user = "Foundation";
        String pwd = "ZDxRvjS3";

        view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('username').value = '"+user+"';document.getElementsByName('passwd').value='"+pwd+"';");
    }
});
```

But when I run my app, I always see one of the values that I have set on a blank page, instead of the website.

Here's a screenshot of what I see:

[image: The example of my result]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try moving `webView.loadUrl("...")` after the other commands. You should open the URL *after* setting up the `webView`. You should also remove a live, working login from a public page like this.

Comment: Thanks very much,but it doesn't work,it is only the last bug of my app :).,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)

Comment: I don't know JavaScript so much,if you could help me about this issue,i would be thankful to you :)

Comment: Did you look at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31291128/5734311