# How can i dynamically change the style (css) applied to a web page in a webview of android application

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

I'm looking for a way to dynamically change the style (css) applied to a web page in a webview. Can someone help me?

For example, I want to be able to dynamically modify the style file to include in the head tag of my html page. Depending on the content of a sharepreference variable, I will change the style of the page.
Thank you.

Comment: You can try to use JS interface to manipulate. All ther required things to start are mentiond here https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview

Comment: I tried this but it only seems useful when I want to run java code from my web page. I could not do the opposite. if you have an example that would be cool

Comment: Actually, you're looking for the way to call js in your java environment, so check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31291128/5356531)

Comment: I tried this but it only seems useful when I want to run java code from my web page. I could not do the opposite. if you have an example that would be cool

Comment: style looking for any help please!