# Delete a character in textarea on webview when press back button

Tags: android, webview, back

I have an android application in which I have a webview. How can I when I press the back button on android I can delete a character in the text area of ​​webview?

```
package com.example.nqc.myapplication;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //delete a character
        Log.d("Debug", "Delete text on TextArea");
    }
}
```

Please see the picture below if you do not understand what I said.

[Before press back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gMQS.png)

[After press back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BA8u.png)

Comment: Do you mean: To back to previous page with previous text that was in the search box?

Comment: No, I mean: press the back button > delete a character (e) in textArea (search box) instead of back to previous page. (This is like pressing the delete button
on the soft keyboard)

Comment: What if you have a page other than *google.com* , Do you want the same behavior? ... Because according to your comment , the *back* button will work as a single-char deleter.... Can you elaborate why exactly you want to achieve this?

Comment: This will happen to all other pages. I need to press the back button on the **remote control** in an android tv application. It is similar to what I described above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee that there will be only one `Form` in the page the user has loaded.

However, if it's for the `Google` Search Form in particular, you can then execute a `JavaScript` to get a `Form` in the `Google.com` page that has `id=tsf` (*which is the unique id of the search form in `Google.com`*).

Nevertheless, you mentioned in your comment:

> This will happen to all other pages

Unless you know the `id` of the form in the page (*which is practically impossible for every page in `WWW` that contains more than one `Form`*).
You can loop through all `Forms` and ***remove*** the last `char` of the *text* in the `Form`'s `input` of type `text`.

---

### Example

First create a method to run the `JS` script (*note that there are different ways to execute a `JS` in `WebView` in Android, for more details in case the following method did not work for you, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)*):

```
public void run(final String script) { 
      mWebView.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() { 
              mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + script); 
          }
      }); 
}
```

---

Then create a method that returns a JS String to:

1. Get all Forms in the page.
2. Cycle through them all.
3. Cycle through the elements of each Form..
4. Set its value to (its old value - last char).

---

```
private String deleteLastCharScript() {
    return  "var listOfForms = document.forms;\n" + 
            "for(var i = 0; i < listOfForms.length; i++) {\n" + 
            "   var elements = listOfForms[i].elements;\n" +
            "   for(var j = 0 ; j < elements.length ; j++){\n" +
            "       var item = elements.item(j);\n" +
            "       item.value = item.value.substring(0, item.value.length - 1);\n" + 
            "   }\n" + 
            "};";       
}
```

---

You can run that script in the `onBackPressed()` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    run(deleteLastCharScript());
}
```

---

### This is [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

Add to Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Create Simple `WebView` Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Implementation in Activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable JS
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    }

    /**
     * Execute JS String Asynchronously
     * @param script
     */
    public void run(final String script) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // run JavaScript asynchronously
            // it works on KitKat onwards
            mWebView.evaluateJavascript(script, null);
        }else {
            // use different thread to run JavaScript asynchronously
            // because evaluateJavascript doesn't work on versions before KitKat
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mWebView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + script);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }


    /**
     * This JS Script tp Loop through all
     * inputs in all forms in the page
     * and remove last char from each
     * @return
     */
    private String deleteLastCharScript() {
        return  "var listOfForms = document.forms;\n" +
                "for(var i = 0; i < listOfForms.length; i++) {\n" +
                "   var elements = listOfForms[i].elements;\n" +
                "   for(var j = 0 ; j < elements.length ; j++){\n" +
                "       var item = elements.item(j);\n" +
                "       item.value = item.value.substring(0, item.value.length - 1);\n" +
                "   }\n" +
                "};";
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        run(deleteLastCharScript());
    }
}
```

---

### Result

[image: Test]