# Call a Javascript function in Android using Jasonette

Tags: javascript, android, jasonette

I´m turning my website into an app using Jasonette, but I'm having trouble passing java values to javascript after success.
I'm using the following code that is working fine:

JSON:

```
"actions": {
    "$foreground": {
    "type": "$reload"
    },
    "test_action": {
    "type": "$util.banner2",
    "success": {
        "type": "$agent.request",
        "options": {
        "id": "$webcontainer",
        "method": "testEcho"
        }
    }
}
```

---

Javascript:

```
$agent.trigger("test_action");
function testEcho(){
    $('#wrapper').find('#test').css({'color':'red'});
}
```

---

Java:

```
JSONObject json_test_value=new JSONObject();
String test_value = "xpto";
json_test_value.put("value1", test_value);
JasonHelper.next("success", action, json_test_value, event, context);
```

I want to get the test_value from java after success, in order to be able to use testEcho (test_value).
It seems simple but for some reason I can not do.

Comment: You can call js on webviev.

Comment: I hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview.

Comment: https://droidmentor.com/bind-javascript-to-android/           there is also turorial check