# How to send string in web view or javascript function from android?

Tags: javascript, android

How to send string in web view or javascript function from  android ?

Could you please tell me why this is not working ?I am trying to call javascript function from android 
I am taking help form here
[Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)

This is working fine

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho('hello')");
```

Why this is not working ?

```
String str = "hello sharma";

webView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho("+str+")");
```

Comment: use the same syntax with single quote and check it bro webView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho('"+str+"')");

Comment: it gives output `+str+` not hello sharma

Comment: hey use the single quote before and after double quotes. like this  ' "+str+" '

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add quotes around the string variable so it is considered a string.

`webView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho('"+str+"')");`

Without them, it will be considered a variable in javascript.