# How to return value from observable to an JavascriptInterface method?

Tags: android, return, observable, rx-java

I need to return values from contacts which are retrieved from the phone with an observable. The problem, is the returning value.

I have the next method in a bridge:

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public String getFavoriteUsers() {
        return getBridgeHelper().getFavoriteUsers();
    }
```

It is calling a method in a helper (which is the class how do the tasks) and inside of this helper:

```
@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    public String getFavoriteUsers() {

        Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
            SharedPreferences sp = getContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String userIdStores = sp.getString(Constants.SP_FAVOURITES, "[]");
            return new Gson().toJson(ContactsManager.findContactsById(ContactsData.getInstance().contactsStored, userIdStores));
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        result -> returnObservedContacts(result),
                        throwable -> LoggerManager.handlesError(TAG, throwable, throwable.getMessage())
                );
    }
```

So, I need to return this result to the previous bridge, but I don't have a clear idea how to do that.

Thanks

**SOLUTION:**

*The solution is to removes subscribe from the Observable and add blockingFirst at the end. Then, we can make the observable to return a value.*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a result from `getFavoriteUsers`, Create a method inside the `<script>` tag inside your website, which accepts the list of `contacts` as a parameter, Then call this method.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview) StackOverflow answer explains how to call a javascript function

Edit: Since loading from `SharedPreference` doesn't take much time and you don't have access to the website, you can load the contacts on the `OnCreate` of the webview page and save results to a global variable, then call `loadUrl` of the webview. After that return the globally saved result on `getFavoriteUsers`

Comment: The only code that I can modify is the Android source. The website part is forbidden. :(

Comment: can you give us the website link

Comment: Is a private project, I don't have the permissions to show it. Sorry