# How do I get access to the html contents of a popup displayed in a webview?

Tags: java, android, popup, processhtml

My application needs to retrieve data from a web site.
I use a `webview` to access the required page. In the page displayed in this `webview` there are links leading to the detailed info that the app needs. When following a link (using the `webView.loadUrl()`) a popup is displayed on top of the `webview`.

The app gets access to the links with the following code:

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new BackgroundScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
        }
    });
```

and

```
public class BackgroundScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html) {
        ...
    }
```

But this `BackgroundScriptInterface` is not called when a popup displays.

How do I get access to the html contents of the popup?

**EDIT**
As suggested by Eddie below, I've tried

```
    webView.evaluateJavascript(item.competDetailUrl, new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
            Log.d("competDetail", s);
        }
    });
```

The popup is still displayed as expected. However the value passed to the `onReceiveValue` callback  is "null".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info the app retrieves from that site do not need to be displayed on the UI. They are parsed and used in the app logic. Hence I have designed the following work-around: I have replaced the original `javascript:apex.navigation.dialog()` by a `javascript:apex.navigation.redirect()` that displays the requested info directly into the `webview` instead of into a popup window.

As the info now comes into the `webview`, it can be accessed by the above `BackgroundScriptInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `webView.evaluateJavascript()` instead of `webView.loadUrl()`, unless you need to work with pre-Kitkat devices

Reference:
[Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)